# Создание Landing Page

Tags: css, html, backbone.js, angularjs, javascript

Хочу создать LP, админка не требуется, только валидация, отправка форм и немного прочих навесов для юзабилити.

Что лучше использовать для таких проектов?

AngularJS, Backbone или другой JS фреймворк?

Answer (score 2):

В идеале - нативный JS.
Но на практике для сайта из пары страниц jQuery хватит с головой.
Ибо зачем ради двух-трёх страниц нагружать код монстрами JS?

Ответ: jQuery + BootStrap.

Comment: + PHP. Если информацию из отправленных форм нужно сохранять в базу.

Comment: @MasterAlex, пых подразумевается.  
Автор про фронтэнд вроде спросил.

Comment: @TheDoctor, автор спросил про создание landing page, а это зачастую не только frontend. Поэтому "вроде спросил" это да, но при этом написал про функционал форм, который  может работать без бэкенда, а может и с ним,

Comment: @MasterAlex, а я и не спорю, просто метки про frontend и вопросы тоже про него.  
Можно подумать и решить, что ответ должен быть про frontend :)  

С другой стороны - кто знает, может, его сервер с лендингом на Node.JS крутится?

Answer (score -1):

Можно и backbone использовать, чтобы было легко поддерживать. Там с серверной частью легко работать с валидацией.